# Javascript code in React Outlook Web Addin is not executed for a non admin account

Tags: reactjs, webpack, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

We developed an Outlook Web addin in React, build with Webpack. It works on the web, on apps, and on desktop.

We have a very strange case we cannot explain with a customer. We did test on a virtual machine (Windows :  10.0.16299.0 ; Office license : Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus ; Outlook desktop version : Outlook for Office 365 MSO 16.0.10730.20264 32 bit) with both administrator account and normal user account :

- Addin is working well with an administrator account, web and desktop.
- Addin is working well on web with non admin account, but JS seems not to be executed on desktop. Static HTML content appears, meaning it is not a network or firewall issue.
- We have another version of the addin, not using Webpack and React, just pure JS : it is working well both on web and desktop, meaning JS can be executed on the non admin account. We can see the addin loaded in the cache files of AppData.

Is there any problem of React based addin which could explain this very strange behavior (why this difference between an admin and non admin account ? how could JS could be interpreted differently depending on the type of account ?) ? Or any known incompatibility with Webpack ?

Microsoft Store developers did not find this problem running tests on the code...

Comment: Can you also try running the add-in in Outlook Web App using Internet Explorer? 
Since Outlook desktop uses an IE control to render the add-in, you may also be able to reproduce the issue in IE. When the JS appears not to execute, do you see any script error? And last, can you clarify, by administrator account, are you referring to an Office 365 administrator's mailbox, or an administrator Windows machine account?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem is that it works well on IE11. No script error. We even went to a 'hello world' javascript addin to ensure it does not come from our code, but it was not working either. By administrator, we mean windows administrator account, but with same outlook credentials. @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT

Comment: Since the issue doesn't repro in IE, I would suggest [attaching a debugger to the running add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane), then reloading the add-in. The reason I suggest this rather than using the F12 debugger is that this will capture any error that occurs when the add-in is started. Can you also clarify in your comment you said that another JS-only add-in isn't working, but in the question text, you mentioned that a pure JS add-in was working.